# How to end loops

Tags: c#, loops

Starting to learn about loops. It seems like these things go on forever because I am not telling it to stop. Problem is I don't know how to tell it to stop. I am assuming a statement such as != but I really do not know.

Anyone care to explain how loops stop?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 namespace ConsoleApplication326
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool triLoop = true;
        while (triLoop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first integer...");
            int firstInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second integer...");
            int secondInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the third integer...");
            int thirdInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if ((firstInt + secondInt > thirdInt) && (secondInt + thirdInt > firstInt) && (firstInt + thirdInt > secondInt))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers {0}, {1}, and {2} CAN represent sides of the same triangle.", firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers {0}, {1}, and {2} CANNOT represent the sides of the same triangle.", firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I noticed you haven't accepted any answers yet - if one of the answers to this question (or others you've posted) helped you solve your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the text (right below the voting buttons).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) statement will "break out" of a loop.

Alternatively, you can just set your boolean value (`triLoop`) to `false`.

Comment: Thats nifty. What if I wanted to prompt whatever user to see if he wanted to continue or not? Would I just a "Y" or "N" to false or true?

Comment: @Azzamean You can - you can make the logic do whatever you choose within there.

Answer (score 4):

> Anyone care to explain how loops stop

While loop will run for as long as the condition within the loop is true. In order to break it you need to set the expression in the while loop to false.

it will stop when you set `triLoop`  to false. You should read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx).

```
while(triLoop)
{
   if(somecondition)
     triLoop = false;   //loop will not run after this
}
```

a basic example of this. This loop will run till 5.

```
int n = 1;
while (n < 6) 
{
     Console.WriteLine("Current value of n is {0}", n);
     n++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `triLoop` to `false`. Or use `break;`.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have explained how the condition works, but if you want to ask the user whether they want to continue, you could add this to the end of your loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
if(Console.ReadLine() == "Y")
    triLoop = false;
```

Then the condition will evaluate to false if the user types "Y", and the loop will end.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple answers.

```
break; //exits the loop and continues with the code
return; //stops the loop and doesn't proceed with the rest of the code
```

In your case, you can also set triloop to false.

Answer (score 1):

use this in loops to stop loops

```
break;
```

Comment: Don't forget that if you realize after posting that another answer (that's better or the same) has already been posted, there's no cost to deleting your post in order to avoid cluttering questions with answers that don't add anything.

Answer (score 1):

as you are using `while` loop

```
while (triLoop)
        {

        }
```

this loop runs while `triLoop` variable is `true`

you need to set it to `false` somewhere within `while` loop

like

```
while (triLoop)
{
    //your code
    // on some condition
    triLoop = false;  
}
```

or

```
while (triLoop)
{
    //your code
    // on some condition
    break;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        while (triLoop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first integer...");
            int firstInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second integer...");
            int secondInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the third integer...");
            int thirdInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if ((firstInt + secondInt > thirdInt) && (secondInt + thirdInt > firstInt) && (firstInt + thirdInt > secondInt))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers {0}, {1}, and {2} CAN represent sides of the same triangle.", firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers {0}, {1}, and {2} CANNOT represent the sides of the same triangle.", firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("press 0 if you want to continue...");
            int flag = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(flag!=0) break;

        }
```

Comment: Or you can change int.Parse and using char like "Y" or "N" as flag value.